# Change a certain string of an automatically printed number in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

I wanted to copy this page http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/lyrics.html in IOS playground to practice but I would like to ask a question and I hope for your help. I created a function called vantanoveBottles, created a variable "texts" of type String and used "for and in" for numbers from 0 ... 5 I created a string constancy in which I entered numbers and text and then I added texts + newLine as in the code.Now if you compare the site when it comes to 1 and says that there are no more beers do not use the number 0, instead I get out so I would basically print example numbers from 1 to 98 inverse with string of text, (and I did this) then come to 1 should not go out "1 bottles of beer on the wall, 1 bottles of beer. \ n" Take one down and pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall. " the 0 must be eliminated must not go out, how do I do? This is a test code

```
func novantanoveBottles () ->String {
    var testi: String = ""

    for numeri in (1...99).reversed() {
        let newLine:String = "\n \(numeri) bottles of beer on the wall, \(numeri) bottles of beer.\n Take one down and pass it around, \(numeri - 1) bottles of beer on the wall. \n"
        testi += newLine
    }

    testi += "\n \n \n No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer. Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall."

    return testi
}

print(novantanoveBottles())
```

Comment: Whats the issue? Looks alright to me

Comment: if you are comparing the page, in last when it comes to "1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.
"Do not print the number 0 instead I print it, how can I do to delete the 0 also me?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean.. check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a check before you add that part of the text

```
for numeri in (1...99).reversed() {
    let newLine:String = "\n \(numeri) bottles of beer on the wall, \(numeri) bottles of beer.\n Take one down and pass it around"
    if numeri != 1 {
        test1 += ", \(numeri - 1) bottles of beer on the wall. \n
    } else {
        test1 += ".\n"
    }
    testi += newLine
}
```

Comment: I always print the 0 in the playground